# simple example how to insert audio file in android

Tags: android, audio

i am trying to insert a audio file into the application which is not showing any kind of error but while am running the program then it is showing some kind of exception that to force close kind of dialog box and here is my code

This is my first activity where am trying to invoke the button into the second activity playing the audio file.

```
public class Audio extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i1 =new Intent(Audio.this,Audio1.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });
    }
}



public class Audio1 extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer eMediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.audio);
            eMediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ab);
            eMediaPlayer.start();

}
}
```

1. audio is my xml file which is empty presently
2. R.raw.ab is the resource file which is 830kb audio file

Comment: Check your logcat and paste it here please

Comment: sorry,do not know what is exactly logcat is? assuming the debug output

Comment: [2011-08-25 18:48:05 - Audio_open] Uploading Audio_open.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-08-25 18:48:10 - Audio_open] Installing Audio_open.apk...
[2011-08-25 18:49:33 - Audio_open] Success!
[2011-08-25 18:49:34 - Audio_open] Starting activity option.matrix.audio1.java on device emulator-5554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should call

```
eMediaPlayer.prepare();
```

before

```
eMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: i have done that it was asking for try and catch block even added that to the code the same problem was there. i.e., force close by the emulator

Comment: i got rid of problem but changed the code . follow the link for answer http://androidword.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-media-player.html    this will help new android programmers